# How to make discord.py bot say what prefix the server is using?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have my bot to have a specific prefix for each server. I want it to be able to say what prefix it's using for that server by using {prefix}help. Below is my code for the prefixes.

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=(get_prefix), intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command("help")
```

Here is to change the prefix.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed to: {prefix}')
```

This is the code i have to show what current prefix the server is using. This is only part of my help command.

```
  embed.add_field(name="Current Prefix", value=f'The current prefix for this server is {get_prefix}', inline=False)
  embed.set_footer(text="I'm strongly recommened for FAMILY FRIENDLY servers!")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I tried this code above and got this,
[image]

Im asking how can i get the bot to say, "The prefix for this server is {prefix}

Comment: Why aren't you passing arguments to `{get_prefix}`?

Comment: Because im still new to coding and i really dont know how to do that. Sorry

Comment: you declare a funtion `def get_prefix(client, message)` with two arguments: `client` & `message`. In order to display what the funtion is returning in your embed you have to give this two arguments. Like `f'The current prefix for this server is {get_prefix(arg1,arg2)}'`

Comment: So does it need to be `f'The current prefix for this server is {get_prefix(client, message)}'` ?

Comment: probably that will solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is outputting a function object because that is what you asked it for. This is a very common mistake in Python, and is a trap that we all fall for every once in a while. You should be able to solve this problem by changing your value to `get_prefix(client, ctx.message)`.

Comment: I’m so glad that you were able to get it working!